# Received data from socketio but doesn't update the state immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io

When `app.js` receive the data sent from the server (as displayed in the console), the setState doesn't refresh the webpage with new data. At line `console.log("Received data queue:", data.queue)`, it returns `undefined` as well. I was expected it to be a specific value since at line console.log(data), it has value stored under key "queue".

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";
import "./chat.css";
import "./styles.css";
import "./queue.css";
import Chat from "./chat";
import io from "socket.io-client";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      queue: [],
      instruction: "",
      user: "",
      hal: "",
      status: "waiting"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
    socket.on("connect", () => {
      console.log("Connected to the socket server");
    });

    socket.on("queueData", (data) => {
      console.log("Received data:", data);
      console.log("Received data queue:", data.queue);
      this.setState({ queue: data.queue }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.queue);
      });
      this.setState({ instruction: data.instruction }, () => {
        console.log(this.state.instruction);
      });
      // other attributes, user, hal, status ignored here for simplicity
    });

    this.socket = socket;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }


  renderData = () => {
    console.log("rendered queue", this.state.queue);
    if (this.state.queue === undefined) {
      return null;
    }
    return this.state.queue.map((task, index) => (
      <CSSTransition key={index} timeout={500} classNames="fade">
        <div
          className={`task-box ${index === 0 && this.state.status === "working" ? "working" : ""
            }`}
        >
          {task}
          {index === 0 && this.state.status === "working" && (
            <div className="loading-icon"></div>
          )}
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Chat userMessage={this.state.user} halMessage={this.state.hal} />
        <div className={"queue-visualization split right " + this.state.status}>
          <TransitionGroup>{this.renderData()}</TransitionGroup>
          <div className="instruction">
            Instruction: {this.state.instruction}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I wish the webpage to be refreshed immediately when it gets new data. I have incorporated callback function into setState, but it's still not working.